# Passport authentication not working on Heroku?

Tags: javascript, heroku, express, mlab, redistogo

My application is a nodejs web applicaiton using express. It serves as a portfolio website with a cms and api.

In my login route I have the following code:

```
passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info){
    if(err){
        return next(err);
    } else if(!user){
        res.format({
            json: function(){
                return error.throw403(req, res, next);
            },
            html: function(){
                return res.redirect('/login');
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log('login route, user');
        console.log(user);
        req.logIn(user, function(err){
            if(err){
                return next(err);
            } else {
                res.format({
                    json: function(){
                        return res.send(user);
                    },
                    html: function(){
                        return res.redirect('/cms/users');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
})(req, res, next);
```

My heroku logs tell me that user is defined and correct. The `req.logIn()` fires off, succeeds, and redirects (as it should) to `/cms/users`. However, I get a 403 at `/cms/users` because `req.user` is not in the request. This makes me think that my sessions are not persisting, but I'm no expert and have no clue what to do next.

I'm using redistogo and mongolab, and both configs were set using the CLI. Any suggestions? I'm stuck! Thanks.

EDIT: I should add that everything is working fine on my local machine.

Comment: I got it, read the redistogo documentation on heroku and kept tweaking my configuration order until it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation is where I should have started.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/redistogo#using-with-node-js

I followed every configuration on that site to the letter and then tweaked app configuration order until it worked.